# Выборка данных из таблицы с проверкой на id

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii

У меня появилась необходимость сделать мини-отчет. И мне необходимо вытащить из разных таблиц определённые ячейки. И вот собственно сам вопрос: У меня есть следующий код (чуть ниже) и мне необходимо выводить данные из таблицы Order но только у тех элементов у которых `id` совпадает с 1 из `order_id` из таблицы workSession.

```
    $workSessions = OrderPayment::find()->where(['status' => OrderPayment::STATUS_PAYED])->all();
    $Ffff = OrderPayment::find()->orderBy('order_id')->select('order_id')->all();

    $workSessi = Order::find()
        ->where(['id' => $workSessions->id])
        ->all();
```

При подобной попытке получить эти данные я получаю NULL. Как мне решить мою задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Как я понимаю тут нужно использовать не $workSessions->id, а $workSessions->order_id.
2. Лучше использовать релейшены. Т.е. что-то типа:

   ```
   $workSessions = OrderPayment::find()->where(['status' => OrderPayment::STATUS_PAYED])->with('order')->all();
   $order = $workSessions->order;
   ```

При условии что в модели OrderPayment есть метод:

```
public function getOrder()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Order::class, ['id' => 'order_id']);
}
```

При таком подходе будет всего два запроса к БД, это достать все order_payment и по ним достать все order. А если без релейшена, то для каждого order_payment будет делаться запрос на получения order для него, что является не оптимальным решением.

Comment: Да, вы правы, нужно именно order_id( просто я пытался разными способами и скорее всего просто забыл изменить это ). + если вас сильно не затруднит, можете подсказать следующее -> Есть таблицы 1, 2, 3 и мне надо найти все элементы из таблицы 2 у которых item_id = item_id(таблица 1) и после чего вытащить все элементы name из таблицы 3 у которых id = item_id из таблицы 2, В таблицу 1

Comment: Тут речь идет об SQL-запросе, правильно? Или необходимо сделать средствами фреймворка?

Comment: Нет именно средствами фреимворка. Да и уже не надо) я сделал своими силами.